# When I really should call refresh function in module curses in Ruby

Tags: ruby

When I really should call `refresh` function manually in module [Curses](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses.html) in Ruby? I think that it's unclear in the docs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `refresh` method points out to the external function `refresh()`:

```
static VALUE
curses_refresh(VALUE obj)
{
    curses_stdscr();
    refresh();
    return Qnil;
}
```

And you can see the documentation of that `refresh()` method in the [curs_refresh manual](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_refresh.3x.html):

> ```
>    The refresh and wrefresh routines (or wnoutrefresh and doupdate) must
>    be called to get actual output to the terminal, as other routines mere‐
>    ly manipulate data structures.  The routine wrefresh copies the named
>    window to the physical terminal screen, taking into account what is al‐
>    ready there to do optimizations.  The refresh routine is the same, us‐
>    ing stdscr as the default window.  Unless leaveok has been enabled, the
>    physical cursor of the terminal is left at the location of the cursor
>    for that window.
> ```

In modern Linux you can see the declaration of that function or macros in `/usr/include/ncurses.h` or `/usr/include/curses.h`. Example:

```
extern NCURSES_EXPORT(int) refresh (void);              /* generated */
#define refresh()       wrefresh(stdscr)
```

And this is the part of Ruby's `curses.c` that refers to the header files:

```
#if defined(HAVE_NCURSES_H)
# include <ncurses.h>
#elif defined(HAVE_NCURSES_CURSES_H)
# include <ncurses/curses.h>
#elif defined(HAVE_CURSES_COLR_CURSES_H)
# ifdef HAVE_STDARG_PROTOTYPES
#  include <stdarg.h>
# else
#  include <varargs.h>
# endif
# include <curses_colr/curses.h>
#else
# include <curses.h>
...
# endif
#endif
```

Comment: So I should call this function even in case of addstr, addch and setpos functions?

Comment: Probably anytime you'd like to show your actual changes to the screen. It depends on the implementation of the curses library. Maybe there are cases where it's not necessary on other functions.

Comment: It is my understanding that if there are no changes to a window, calling wrefesh() does nothing. But I can't seem to find any documentation or examples about how that works. Does curses keep track of changes or do I have to do that?

Comment: @James Sorry but I don't know, and it's already been a while since I touched [n]curses. The best thing you can do is study the behavior through the source code if you can't find a documentation.